# Using VBA to check if a cell contains a date and if so advancing the date one month

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column of data (C) that has many cells that contain dates. I am trying to create a macro that checks to see if each cell contains a date and if it does then advance the date on month. I have the code to advance the date one month from here http://excel.tips.net/T002180_Automatically_Advancing_by_a_Month.html and it works fine but I am not sure how to replace the range with a dynamic range that evaluates all cells in column C. If possible I would also like to eliminate the need for a loop. Here is what I have so far.

```
Sub IncreaseMonth()
    Dim dDate As Date
    Dim NumberofTasks As Integer
        NumberofTasks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("Number_of_Tasks")
    Dim x As Integer

    For x = 1 To NumberofTasks
        dDate = Range("C30").Value
        Range("C30").Value = _
            DateSerial(Year(dDate), _
            Month(dDate) + 1, Day(dDate))
    Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like the code below (I use `DateAdd` function to add 1 Month to the current date value)

```
Sub IncreaseMonth()

    Dim dDate As Date
    Dim NumberofTasks As Long
    Dim x As Long

    With Worksheets("Dashboard")
        ' I suspect you want to get the last row with data in Column C
        NumberofTasks = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        For x = 1 To NumberofTasks
            If IsDate(.Range("C" & x).Value) Then '<-- check if current cell at Column C is Date
                .Range("C" & x).Value = DateAdd("m", 1, .Range("C" & x).Value) '<-- add 1 Month to current date in Column c, use DateAdd function
            End If
        Next x

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet should put you on the right track. I'm making a couple of assumptions here. The first is that you have a named range called "Number_of_Tasks" on which you wish to operate. Second is that all values in this range are a valid date. If values could be an invalid date (like a blank) you should check for this before setting the value.

You will also wish to ensure that the month does not become invalid. Incrementing the month past December will not be a valid date.

```
Sub IncreaseMonth()
    Dim tempCell As Range
    For Each tempCell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("Number_of_Tasks")
        tempCell.Value = DateSerial(Year(tempCell.value), Month(tempCell.value) + 1, Day(tempCell.value))
    Next tempCell
```